# How to pull a docker image from Azure Registry in a Azure Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu

I have created an Azure Registry where I deploy some docker container from the CD\CI in Azure DevOps.

Following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal#code-try-0), I have created a service principal. So, I have username and password to use to pull images from the Azure Container Registry. I tried to pull the images locally and it is working. To connect to the Container registry I use this command:

> docker login myazureregistry.azurecr.io --username  --password

[image]

Now, I want to create a virtual machine in Azure to publicly access to the application in the container.

I created an Ubuntu virtual machine and installed Docker. I run the same command as before on the Ubuntu machine but I got an error:

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/auth: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

[image]

What is the problem? How have I to configure Ubuntu to connect to the Azure Container?

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem? Or what's else you expect?

Comment: I have created a post where I explain the entire process end-to-end for deploying ShinyProxy and ShinyApps with Docker and Azure https://www.puresourcecode.com/programming-languages/r/deploy-shinyapps-with-azure-and-docker/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have permissions for use docker.
Add your user to docker group for use docker command without *sudo*

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

And after this run your login command. (If you use virtual machine, it may be necessary to restart the virtual machine for changes to take effect)

Comment: I tried the command you suggest but the group `docker` already exists and the second command returns 4 _existing_

Comment: You can run your login command with sudo, because your don't have enough right to use  unixsocket for communicate with docker.